# Rewrite only specific route with nginx Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have three services running in my backend and the Ingress routing is defined like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: acme-crt-secret
  rules:
  - host: myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-mvc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-api
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /identity
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp-identity
          servicePort: 80
```

The problem is that *myapp-api* is already listening for requests to `/api/v1/myresource`. With the current configuration, the *myapp-api* service only serves requests to `myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/api/v1/myresource` (please note the .../api/api/...).

Is it possible to serve requests to `/api` by the myapp-api service but rewriting these requests to `/` for the service without creating another Ingress? So, myapp-api should serve requests to `myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/myresource`.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Not fully satisfactory. In my case I use .NET Core for the service, which provides a middleware for http requests (`UsePathBase(...)`) that extracts the first path. I think other options would be to use a different ingress implementation other than nginx, or to use multiple ingresses.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

a) Change the port of the API and have it serve / on that port.

b) Change your app so it will serve the API on "/v1/myresource" and give it the "api" part of the URL through the Ingress.

Either way, you'll have your resources at "myapp.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/api/v1/myresource".

Comment: I'm aware of option b) but I'd like to leave the api service unchanged. Could you elaborate a bit more on how approach a) can be achieved? I don't really understand how to accomplish this.