# Nginx ingress rewrite target breaks link to .NET Core API

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've got a setup with multiple services and are run via an Ingress / Terraform / Kubernetes setup. Currently, all my Vue.JS applications are served via NGINX however when I added the following line `"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$1"` to make sure my other routes work such as /frontend and /backend it broke my API and I can no longer access it via `/api/`

Terraform setup:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
metadata {
name      = "ingress"
namespace = var.namespace_name
annotations = {
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect" = true
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect" = true
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": true
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url": false
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$1"
  "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"
  "ncp/use-regex": true
}
}

spec {
tls {
  hosts = [var.domain_name, "*.${var.domain_name}"]
  secret_name = "tls-secret"
}
rule {
  host = var.domain_name
  http {
    path {
      path = "/(.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "frontend"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/api(.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "api"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/backend(.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "backend"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/payment(.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "payment"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

  }
 }
}

wait_for_load_balancer = true
}
```

My `Startup.cs` config

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OLC API V1");
        });

        app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseRouting();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

The terraform setup seems to work for all my vue.js containers. Only problem is that API is no longer accessible. Not even via /api/api such as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820476/rewrite-only-specific-route-with-nginx-ingress)

I've tried to rewrite only specific routes and change the app so that'd serve on a different route but I still get a `404` error. Even when creating a controller that responds to the `/` route. When removing the rewrite target line the API does work. But the Vue.JS containers do not

Comment: Could you show your Ingress yaml? I mean without the Terraform setup. Would that be possible for you?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, my Terraform setup makes the ingress.yaml; so I don't have a separate one without that setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, this is simply a regex issue and me not setting paths correctly. I changed the following.

```
 path {
  path = "/api(.*)"
  backend {
    service_name = "api"
    service_port = 80
  }
}
```

Into

```
     path {
      path = "/(api.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "olc-api"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }
```

With this it matches the /api to my .NET core app, instead of it trying to find a URL within the vue.js container(s)